# how to set default txn isolation level per connection when using spring boot and jooq

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jooq

I am using Spring Boot with JOOQ (not spring data).

I would like to set the default transaction isolation for each jdbc connection to `serializable`. 
How do i do so?

Comment: First tell us please how are you handling transactions? By Spring Transaction Manager or you have some custom solution?

Comment: using jooq transactions (https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/)

Answer (score -1):

You are using JOOQ transactions. They do not support transaction isolation:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4836

I'd suggest you to use Spring transactions. Then you get also transaction isolation:

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void xxxMethod(...) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: the question is how to set isolation on a per connection jdbc level. it specifically mentions spring data is not being used.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked issue, you should be able to use JDBC API (specifically `Connection#setTransactionIsolation()`) to set your isolation level. Depending on how you set up your `Configuration`, you may want to create your own `ConnectionProvider` to do this.

Comment: @pdeva: `@Transactional` has nothing to do with Spring Data. It is normally used with JPA or JDBC. That's why this solution corresponds to your requirements/expectations. Create a JDBC connection within a transaction that is handled by Spring Transaction Manager and you get isolation that you need. Of course it depends if your database supports this isolation. But you want SERIALIZABLE, and the most of the DB do support it.

Comment: @pdeva: Also the page you linked refers Spring Transaction Manager. Please explain why don't you want to use Spring Transaction Manager.

Comment: @pdeva: I think you don't distinguish Spring Data and Spring Transaction Manager. Spring Data is relatively new module in Spring. The Spring Transaction Manager exists much longer, it is a *separate* module in Spring, `spring-tx`. It would be good if you read a little bit about Spring before you down vote answers that you don't understand. If don't understand, just ask :)